# Dereference may produce NullPointerException when using getter

Tags: java, android

I'm using a custom View class with an instance reference which serves as an Editor. View is only used in a fragment. I need the instance reference so I can always get custom parameters of the custom View.

```
public static StoryView instance;
private Story story;

public static Story getCurrentStory(){
    if(instance == null) return null;
    else return instance.story;
}
```

However, when I'm using this getter method to change the contents of Navigation Drawer, I'm getting a warning:

[image]

In here:

```
private static IDrawerItem[] drawerEditorItems(){
    Story s = StoryView.getCurrentStory();
    SectionDrawerItem section_editor = new SectionDrawerItem()
         .withName(str("placeholder_story_by", s.name, s.author))
         .withDivider(false);
    return new IDrawerItem[]{ section_editor };
}
```

`str(String id, Object... args)` is a static method that basically formats i18n strings.

---

My guess is that the reference `s` is getting destroyed at the end of the function scope maybe by assigning `s = null`? And maybe that might destroy the actual `instance.story` from my custom View?

Comment: **Nothing** is happening to `s`. This is a *compile-time* message, and it is a *warning*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you call

```
public static Story getCurrentStory(){
    if(instance == null) return null;
    else return instance.story;
}
```

You check to make sure instance isn't null. If it is, you return null. What may be the case here is that instance is always null(never initialized). Meaning you have to ensure instance is initialized before calling it if you want to get the current story.

<sub>Also, this is technically not necessary. Returning a null instance is equivalent to checking if it's null, then returning null. you can also use `@NotNull` and `@Nullable` to help both the compiler, yourself, and anyone else working on the code/interacting with it.</sub>

Further, it may still return null in some cases, so you want to add a check to ensure it isn't null. This can be done using an if-statement:

```
if(s != null){
    //Do whatever
}
```

But the reason you are getting that warning is (in my experience) when it is almost guaranteed you will get an exception. take this for an instance:

```
View v = null;
v.setText("");
```

That shows the exact same warning as you are getting. So, most likely, your method will return null no matter what. So you have to make sure `instance` is initialized, and have an if-statement to make sure the app doesn't crash if it is null. Initializing `instance` is a way to ensure you get a reference that isn't null

Comment: `StoryView.instance` is supposed to be `null` only in one case: if the editor wasn't loaded/initialized yet. User is supposed to select the story he wants to edit, but before that the custom View (editor) and the StoryViewFragment are nonexistant. The method which makes the navigation drawer actually gets one parameter - if the editor is empty or not, which is passed like this: `drawer.setItems(Arrays.asList(drawerEditorItems(StoryView.getCurrentStory() == null)));`

Comment: In that event, the only thing you can do with the warning you received is make sure it isn't null. Using an if-statement is one of the easiest ways, but in some cases you can use the `?` operator. In this case though, the best way to go is using an if-statement

Comment: Alright. I just changed my function so instead of passing the boolean argument which is determined by `StoryView.ge‌​tCurrentStory() == null` it's getting checked inside the function, eliminating the need of any arguments and the warning itself. Thanks for a reply, your answer is now marked as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

It is just a warning for possible NPE (NullPointerException). What you should do is write a null check for `s` before dereferencing it. That's it.

```
if(s != null){
// Call to s.method();

}
```

Ultimately, you have to ensure that any reference you are getting must not be de-referenced when it is `NULL`.

Personally, I have encountered several situations of not checking before dereferencing and these turn out to be bugs most of the times. Google, when developed Guava took the NPE problem into consideration and put it into their design for robustness.

Comment: So it's actually like "Method invokation might produce NPE" but for fields?

Comment: @WearyAdventurer : It doesn't matter if its field or method. If you have a NULL reference, you can't reference anything through it. Simple.

Comment: @WearyAdventurer if I understand your code correctly, you are getting a reference that may be null. Android Studio shows you that warning to add an if-statement to make sure s isn't null. So using pulp_fiction's solution is the best way to go about it.